# PHP Htmlentities - double encoded

Tags: php, html-entities

What condition we use to decide when to set double encoded is true or false?
What php settings variable we can use to decide it?

For Russian character, it should use double encoded true then it will display the character.
But if double encoded is false, the string will be displayed as empty.
What condition we use to set double encoded true or false?

Answer (score 4):

You can change that with the 4th argument. Set it to `FALSE` to not double encode.

```
$str = 'Hot & Cold and On &amp; Off';

var_dump(htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE));
```

#### Output

```
string(31) "Hot &amp; Cold and On &amp; Off"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/VL4sPl4a).

Comment: i mean for russian character, it should use double encoded true then it will display the character. But if double encoded is false, the string will be displayed as empty

Comment: @Julianto I'm not sure what you mean sorry :(

Comment: i am trying to display language string using htmlentities.
echo htmlentities($lang_name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);

above code will display var $name if module mod_charset_lite is enabled. If mod_charset_lite is off, it will display nothing